# Should I store daily user count in a table that is updated by a cron job?

Tags: postgresql, cron

I need to get the `user` count for each `account` every day. `Accounts` can create and delete users, so I don't think a simple aggregate function will work since if an `account` had 10 `users` yesterday and deletes one `user` today (so they have 9 `users` today), I'd still like to know that there were 10 `users` yesterday.

My current solution is to have a user count table that gets updated by a cron job everyday (see implementation below). Was wondering if there was a better way?

```sql
CREATE TABLE account (
  account_id bigint primary key
);

CREATE TABLE person (
  person_id    bigint primary key,
  account_id   bigint,
  created_at   timestamptz default now(),

  foreign key (account_id) references account
);

CREATE TABLE person_count (
  primary key (account_id, day),
  account_id   bigint,
  person_count integer,
  day          timestamptz,

  constraint day_formatted_dates_only check (day = date_trunc('day', day)),

  foreign key (account_id) references account
);

-- cron job that runs everyday
CREATE FUNCTION count_person_by_account()
RETURNS void AS $$

  INSERT INTO person_count
              (account_id, person_count, day)
       SELECT p.account_id, COUNT(*) person_count, date_trunc('day', now())
         FROM person p
     GROUP BY p.account_id

$$ LANGUAGE SQL
   VOLATILE;
```

Answer (score 0):

After thinking about it some more I've decided not to go in that direction and instead create a view for person.

```sql
CREATE TABLE hidden_schema.person (
  person_id    bigint primary key,
  account_id   bigint,
  created_at   timestamptz default now(),
  is_deleted   boolean,

  foreign key (account_id) references account
);

CREATE VIEW visible_schema.person AS
  SELECT person_id, account_id, created_at
    FROM hidden_schema.person
   WHERE is_deleted = false;

-- Then I'll run the aggregate function on hidden_schema.person
```

edit:
After thinking about it even more, I realized an easier way would be to not use a view and just add an is_delete flag (as above) and use row level security to filter it out for by my client role

```sql
CREATE TABLE person (
  person_id    bigint primary key,
  account_id   bigint,
  created_at   timestamptz default now(),
  is_deleted   boolean,

  foreign key (account_id) references account
);

ALTER TABLE person ENABLE ROW LEVEL SECURITY;

CREATE POLICY select_for_public_facing_client_role
           ON person
          FOR SELECT
           TO public_facing_client_role
        USING (is_deleted = false);
```

Also, to answer the original question of getting daily user count, I'm using a lateral join

```sql
SELECT day, account_id, count
  FROM (
  SELECT generate_series AS day
    FROM generate_series('2020-10-14'::timestamptz, '2020-10-20'::timestamptz, '1d'::interval)
) d LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT account_id, COUNT(*)
    FROM person
   WHERE created_at <= d.day
GROUP BY account_id
) c ON TRUE
ORDER BY d.day, c.account_id;
```

You can't run this as the public_facing_client_role because they can't see deleted persons. Can use a materialized view with a where clause for authorization.